# Update field in one table using data from another based on a key value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I need to update the Notes field in my table tblMain by concatenating the text data with the Notes field in my secondary table tblSecond by matching the ID field in both tables.

I was using the following SQL:

```
UPDATE tblMain
SET tblMain.Notes = (tblMain.Notes + (SELECT DISTINCT Notes FROM tblSecond
WHERE tblSecond.ID = tblMain.ID))
```

but I get the following error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

presumably because the SELECT statement is returning an entire resultset.

How would I perform this operation successfully?

Comment: I just tried it again using a MERGE

`MERGE INTO tblMain
 USING 
 (
   SELECT ID, notes
   FROM tblSecond
 ) Second ON (Second.ID = tblMain.ID)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
 SET tblMain.Notes = tblMain.Notes + Second.notes`

but I get a similar error:
`The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: I assume in the tblSecond table you can have multiple notes for a single record in tblMain?  In other words, it may be possible to concatenate multiple records from tblSecond into a single tblMain record?

Comment: If there are two rows in Second that correspond to one row in Main, are you looking to concatenate both rows into Main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will handle if subquery returns more than 1 value.

```
UPDATE tblmain 
SET    tblmain.notes = ( tblmain.notes 
                         + (SELECT DISTINCT notes + ' ' 
                            FROM   tblsecond 
                            WHERE  tblsecond.id = tblmain.id 
                            FOR xml path ('')) )
```

Answer (score 1):

If the subquery returns more than 1 value, it means that tblSecond contains more than 1 entry for the corresponding ID. So I would suggest to first check your data.

The update itself can also be written using the `from` clause, something like this (untested)

```
update tblMain
    set Notes = a.Notes + b.Notes
from
    tblMain a
    inner join tblSecond b on a.Id = b.Id
```

Comment: tblMain will have the only last value that was concatenated to notes.

Comment: either correct the post or delete because it will create confusion for other readers. it will help you to avoid downvoting also.